# Kotlin anko onclick is unresolved reference

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, anko

I am new to Kotlin and anko, I am phasing an error on android studio 3.0 beta 6,Kotlin version 1.1.50 and anko 0.10.1
Error:
Kotlin anko onclick is unresolved reference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from: https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/issues/412

From the [releases page](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/releases/tag/v0.10) under 0.10 I find:

> DSL listeners moved to anko-< platformName >-listeners artifacts (e.g.
>   anko-sdk25-listeners);